# Node RED mandar notificacion solo una vez

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy aprendiendo a usar este programa y me encuentro en una situacion en la cual nose como avanzar. Hago esto para aprender. Tengo la siguiente situacion. Una API que lee un balanace y se lo pasa a un nodo el cual chequea cual es el balance y en caso de ser superior a x este envia una notificacion por telegram. Esta parte del codigo ya esta hecha y funciona, el inconveniente que tengo es que la lectura del balance se hace cada 30 segundos y cuando la funcion se activa me envia una notificacion cada 30 segundos. Como hago para que se envie una notificacion y tener un timeout de por ejemplo 1 hora para volver a mandar una notificacion de volver a activarse la funcion? Mis nodos actuales son los siguientes:

```
//1 CHEQUEAR EL BALANCE
msg.payload = msg.payload.data.balance
if (msg.payload >= 1) {
    msg.payload = {
        send: true,
        string: `Balance: ${msg.payload}`
    }
    return msg;
} else {
    msg.payload = {
        send: false,
        string: "Not ready!"
    }
    return msg;
}

//2 EJECUTA LA NOTIFICACION
if (msg.payload.send == true) {
    msg.payload = msg.payload.string;
return msg;
}

// 3 CREA EL MENSAJE PARA TELEGRAM
msg.payload = {chatId :35(chatId)100, type : 'message', content : 
msg.payload}
return msg;
```

Cual seria el modo correcto de hacer lo que quiero hacer? Intente buscar sobre administracion de tiempos en Node RED pero no encontre mucha informacion. Les agradeceria si me apuntan hacia donde leer o las distintas opciones para conseguir este tipo de acciones. Que anden bien!!

Comment: Me auto respondo la pregunta xD, hay que usar el nodo trigger y configurarlo para que solo se pueda mandar cada x tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes usar el nodo RBE

Según el cual el dato de entrada solo pasa si ha cambiado.
Ademas te permite elegir el modo y la cantidad del cambio.

ej puedes bloquear todos los datos hasta que haya un incremento del 5%

aquí tienes un ejemplo:
[image: esquema node-red ejemplo modulo RBE]
En este ejemplo el payload solo pasa si ha cambiado mas de 10000

Código del ejemplo:

```
[{"id":"de18fef1.770df8","type":"rbe","z":"dc1bc631.8d05e","name":"","func":"deadband","gap":"10000","start":"","inout":"out","property":"payload","x":235,"y":505,"wires":[["1ce27cf9.47c573"]]},{"id":"1ce27cf9.47c573","type":"debug","z":"dc1bc631.8d05e","name":"debug","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":370,"y":505,"wires":[]},{"id":"b3517b20.b5acf8","type":"inject","z":"dc1bc631.8d05e","name":"test","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"1","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":95,"y":475,"wires":[["de18fef1.770df8","bed05dc0.b4c588"]]},{"id":"bed05dc0.b4c588","type":"debug","z":"dc1bc631.8d05e","name":"debug","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":370,"y":460,"wires":[]}]
```

Copiar texto y En node-red => Menu => importar => clipboard => pegar texto